# Ocultar ou excluir linha da tabela quando deletar o registro

Tags: php, html, ajax

Tenho uma tabela que exibe uma lista de clientes e tem um cotão ao lado para excluir cada cliente. Quero fazer essa exclusão via ajax, como faço para que a linha que está o cliente que foi excluído sumir sem ter que atualizar a página?

Obs: Estou usando o plugin jQuery Datatable

```
<table id="appDatatable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody>
    @foreach($clientes as $cliente)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $cliente->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $cliente->telefone }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                ...
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Excluir cliente"
                   onclick="conf('{{ $cliente->id }}');">
                    <span class="fa fa-close"></span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posta os trechos relevantes do seu código que eu posso ajudar a resolver. Mas o truque é executar a ação de remoção da linha no retorno de sucesso da requisição ajax

Answer (score 2):

Costumo usar assim:

```
$("#tabela").on("click",".deletaBtn", function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.css("background-color","yellow");
    tr.fadeOut(600, function(){
        tr.remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Onde .detelaBtn é a classe definida no botão de exclusão

Não sei se o Datatable tem uma função própria pra isso. Ve ai se ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

O jQuery DataTable possui o método [`fnDeleteRow`](https://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.4/DataTable.html#fnDeleteRow) para excluir uma linha da tabela.

Após o retorno de sucesso do seu `AJAX`, você pode incluir por exemplo:

```
var tabela = $('#tabela').dataTable();
tabela.fnDeleteRow( N ); // onde N é o índice da linha a ser excluída da tabela
```

Comment: Como eu faria pra pega esse índice e mandar junto com o id do cliente quando eu chamo a função onclick="conf('{{ $cliente->id }}');" ?